# How Extending LUKS2

Tags: luks

I read a guide few years ago that's on how LUKS1 extending to the right and adjacent freespace without data loss, but could not left. Nowadays LUKS2 has arrived with many new features, does it makes differents on the left extending without data lossing
??

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr** It's not really possible - yet. The metadata format suggests it should be doable, but so far, it's not actually implemented. So you should stick to the good old "relocate all data", or "create new partition and let LVM worry about it". Same thing you do with LUKS1 and most filesystems.

---

The [LUKS2 header](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/LUKS2-docs) has a concept of *data segments*:

> Segments object contains a definition of encrypted areas on the disk containing user data (in LUKS1 mentioned as the user data payload). For a normal LUKS device, there is only one data segment present.
>
> During the data reencryption, the data area is internally divided according to the new and the old key, but only one abstracted area should be presented to the user.

With *data segments*, it should be possible to move the LUKS header to the left, keep pointing to the original data (first segment), and use the free space (between header and data segment) as a new data segment, logically appended to the end of the crypt device. Just like how LVM appends arbitrary groups of physical extents to a Logical Volume.

But that's just a theory.

As of yet, there is no practical use / tool that implements this feature and I have no idea if there are any plans to do so.

---

I tried to make it work the unconventional way (proof of concept, kind of):

```
# truncate -s 100M foobar.img
# cryptsetup luksFormat --type=luks2 foobar.img
# cryptsetup luksOpen foobar.img foobar
# yes > /dev/mapper/foobar
# sync
# hexdump -C /dev/mapper/foobar
00000000  79 0a 79 0a 79 0a 79 0a  79 0a 79 0a 79 0a 79 0a  |y.y.y.y.y.y.y.y.|
*
05400000
```

LUKS2 encrypted yes-pattern. What's the data segment like?

```
# cryptsetup luksDump foobar.img
Data segments:
  0: crypt
    offset: 16777216 [bytes]
    length: (whole device)
    cipher: aes-xts-plain64
    sector: 512 [bytes]
# strings -n 100 foobar.img
"segments":{"0":{"type":"crypt","offset":"16777216","iv_tweak":"0","size":"dynamic","encryption":"aes-xts-plain64","sector_size":512}}
```

The latter is actually what raw LUKS2 metadata looks like - it's a JSON format. We'll edit that later...

Let's grow it - to the left (by 100M):

```
# truncate -s 100M barfoo.img
# cat foobar.img >> barfoo.img
# ls -lh *.img
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 200M Jun  9 20:57 barfoo.img
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 100M Jun  9 20:53 foobar.img
```

So barfoo.img is 100M of new empty space followed by 100M original LUKS container.

Relocate the LUKS header to new start of device:

```
# dd bs=1M count=16 if=foobar.img of=barfoo.img conv=notrunc
# cryptsetup luksOpen barfoo.img barfoo
# hexdump -C -n 16 /dev/mapper/barfoo
00000000  4e a6 39 e7 e0 e8 63 ae  81 72 29 81 5f 1b 08 c2  |N.9...c..r)._...|
00000010
```

It can be opened now, but the *data segment* still points to the old offset (16MiB) but of course, it's not there - we added 100M so the offset for this *data segment* should be 116MiB now.

Edit it (offset 16777216 to offset 121634816):

```
# strings -n 100 barfoo.img | head -n 1 > barfoo.json
# nano -w barfoo.json
# dd if=barfoo.json of=barfoo.img bs=1 seek=4096 conv=notrunc
# dd if=barfoo.json of=barfoo.img bs=1 seek=20480 conv=notrunc
```

Result:

```
# cryptsetup luksDump barfoo.img
Device barfoo.img is not a valid LUKS device.
```

Oh, but of course. LUKS2 also has metadata checksums now. It doesn't want you to edit stuff with nano and mangle the header with dd. No arcane magic for you, sir. Well, that is until you patch the checksum too...

```
# cryptsetup luksDump barfoo.img --debug
# LUKS2 header version 2 of size 16384 bytes, checksum sha256.
# Checksum:8552bf514ab70b53e63180e9fdd3bb59db1385e3dca87f792f8197b33b851aa1 (on-disk)
# Checksum:e6f322921feae0193bcbc4cddc23b87b7f192266b4a2ef34847580fd7ca18a3e (in-memory)
# LUKS2 header checksum error (offset 0).
```

...basically replace the on-disk checksum with the in-memory one here.

```
# echo e6f322921feae0193bcbc4cddc23b87b7f192266b4a2ef34847580fd7ca18a3e |
  xxd -r -ps - |
  dd of=barfoo.img bs=1 seek=448 conv=notrunc
```

Result (now really):

```
# cryptsetup luksDump barfoo.img
Data segments:
  0: crypt
    offset: 121634816 [bytes]
    length: (whole device)
    cipher: aes-xts-plain64
    sector: 512 [bytes]
# hexdump -C /dev/mapper/barfoo
00000000  79 0a 79 0a 79 0a 79 0a  79 0a 79 0a 79 0a 79 0a  |y.y.y.y.y.y.y.y.|
*
05400000
```

At this point, we've successfully moved the LUKS header 100M to the left. But the device size is still the same... now, can we add another data segment? There's a free 100M segment from offset 16M to 116M. Let's add it to the JSON.

```
# nano -w barfoo.json
man this is unreadable
# jq < barfoo.json > barfoo.pretty
# nano -w barfoo.pretty
...
  "segments": {
    "0": {
      "type": "crypt",
      "offset": "121634816",
      "iv_tweak": "0",
      "size": "88080384",
      "encryption": "aes-xts-plain64",
      "sector_size": 512
    },
    "1": {
      "type": "crypt",
      "offset": "16777216",
      "iv_tweak": "172032",
      "size": "104857600",
      "encryption": "aes-xts-plain64",
      "sector_size": 512
    }
  },
  "digests": {
    "0": {
      "type": "pbkdf2",
      "keyslots": [
        "0"
      ],
      "segments": [
        "0",
        "1"
      ],
...and so on and so forth...
```

Result:

```
# cryptsetup luksDump barfoo.img
Data segments:
  0: crypt
    offset: 121634816 [bytes]
    length: 88080384 [bytes]
    cipher: aes-xts-plain64
    sector: 512 [bytes]

  1: crypt
    offset: 16777216 [bytes]
    length: 104857600 [bytes]
    cipher: aes-xts-plain65
    sector: 512 [bytes]
```

Unfortunately, at this point, the device opened fine, had the correct increased size (YAY!), but the data was wrong (NOO!). Logical byte 0 was mapped to physical byte 16MiB instead of the expected 116MiB.

Hey, that's segment 1, not segment 0, you silly billy! What went wrong?

I don't know. It's almost as if you're not supposed to do simple metadata modifications to unlock hidden features that no one has ever tested yet.

Maybe it's due to my lack of understanding, but even when putting the segments the other way around, it would still keep opening them in the wrong order. Something is sorting these by physical offset? But why?

So unfortunately this particular piece of magic ended in a failure. Either because I did something wrong, or it's just not ready for use yet. Still, the functionality is kind-of there - so there is still hope for the future.

Note that even if it did work, you'd be ill advised to use it.