# LUKS2: ERROR: Forbidden ascii code 0x53 found beyond json data string at offset 4096

Tags: linux, data-recovery, luks, disk-encryption

I'm trying to open a LUKS2 partition, which is back-upped into a raw image, together with some other drives. Testdisk was able to show the start sector but wasn't able to get the end, so I extracted that specific sector till the end of the image to a file called `image.img`. But opening the LUKS partition fails and returns a `Device image.img is not a valid LUKS device` message.

I printed the first bytes of *image.img* and the header seems fine:

```
$ hexdump -Cn 400 hidden
00000000  4c 55 4b 53 ba be 00 02  00 00 00 00 00 00 40 00  |LUKS..........@.|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 04  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00000040  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  73 68 61 32 35 36 00 00  |........sha256..|
00000050  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000060  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  d2 60 cf 74 cb 3b 37 e5  |.........`.t.;7.|
00000070  70 96 d1 82 bc 9f 15 3f  43 77 68 ec da b0 63 28  |p......?Cwh...c(|
00000080  76 9b 86 af 6c 9d bf b9  9e fe 74 3d 74 37 31 2c  |v...l.....t=t71,|
00000090  4a af 79 9d 7a 2e 4a 51  eb cd 13 35 06 29 33 a9  |J.y.z.JQ...5.)3.|
000000a0  b0 f6 70 8e 7e 34 51 71  39 33 38 38 39 64 37 61  |..p.~4Qq93889d7a|
000000b0  2d 33 65 66 30 2d 34 35  34 34 2d 38 39 62 39 2d  |-3ef0-4544-89b9-|
000000c0  61 62 64 35 63 62 32 33  38 33 64 65 00 00 00 00  |abd5cb2383de....|
000000d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
```

There are even JSON headers available:

```
hexdump -Cs 4096 -n 10002 hidden
00001000  7b 22 6b 65 79 73 6c 6f  74 73 22 3a 7b 22 30 22  |{"keyslots":{"0"|
00001010  3a 7b 22 74 79 70 65 22  3a 22 6c 75 6b 73 32 22  |:{"type":"luks2"|
00001020  2c 22 6b 65 79 5f 73 69  7a 65 22 3a 36 34 2c 22  |,"key_size":64,"|
00001030  61 66 22 3a 7b 22 74 79  70 65 22 3a 22 6c 75 6b  |af":{"type":"luk|
00001040  73 31 22 2c 22 73 74 72  69 70 65 73 22 3a 34 30  |s1","stripes":40|
00001050  30 30 2c 22 68 61 73 68  22 3a 22 73 68 61 32 35  |00,"hash":"sha25|
00001060  36 22 7d 2c 22 61 72 65  61 22 3a 7b 22 74 79 70  |6"},"area":{"typ|
00001070  65 22 3a 22 72 61 77 22  2c 22 6f 66 66 73 65 74  |e":"raw","offset|
00001080  22 3a 22 33 32 37 36 38  22 2c 22 73 69 7a 65 22  |":"32768","size"|
00001090  3a 22 32 35 38 30 34 38  22 2c 22 65 6e 63 72 79  |:"258048","encry|
000010a0  70 74 69 6f 6e 22 3a 22  61 65 73 2d 78 74 73 2d  |ption":"aes-xts-|
000010b0  70 6c 61 69 6e 36 34 22  2c 22 6b 65 79 5f 73 69  |plain64","key_si|
000010c0  7a 65 22 3a 36 34 7d 2c  22 6b 64 66 22 3a 7b 22  |ze":64},"kdf":{"|
...
00001410  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00002000  53 4b 55 4c ba be 00 02  00 00 00 00 00 00 40 00  |SKUL..........@.|
00002010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 04  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00002020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00002040  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  73 68 61 32 35 36 00 00  |........sha256..|
00002050  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  
 ...
00003000  7b 22 6b 65 79 73 6c 6f  74 73 22 3a 7b 22 30 22  |{"keyslots":{"0"|
00003010  3a 7b 22 74 79 70 65 22  3a 22 6c 75 6b 73 32 22  |:{"type":"luks2"|
00003020  2c 22 6b 65 79 5f 73 69  7a 65 22 3a 36 34 2c 22  |,"key_size":64,"|
00003030  61 66 22 3a 7b 22 74 79  70 65 22 3a 22 6c 75 6b  |af":{"type":"luk|
00003040  73 31 22 2c 22 73 74 72  69 70 65 73 22 3a 34 30  |s1","stripes":40|
00003050  30 30 2c 22 68 61 73 68  22 3a 22 73 68 61 32 35  |00,"hash":"sha25|
00003060  36 22 7d 2c 22 61 72 65  61 22 3a 7b 22 74 79 70  |6"},"area":{"typ|
00003070  65 22 3a 22 72 61 77 22  2c 22 6f 66 66 73 65 74  |e":"raw","offset|
00003080  22 3a 22 33 32 37 36 38  22 2c 22 73 69 7a 65 22  |":"32768","size"|
00003090  3a 22 32 35 38 30 34 38  22 2c 22 65 6e 63 72 79  |:"258048","encry|
000030a0  70 74 69 6f 6e 22 3a 22  61 65 73 2d 78 74 73 2d  |ption":"aes-xts-|
000030b0  70 6c 61 69 6e 36 34 22  2c 22 6b 65 79 5f 73 69  |plain64","key_si|
000030c0  7a 65 22 3a 36 34 7d 2c  22 6b 64 66 22 3a 7b 22  |ze":64},"kdf":{"|
000030d0  74 79 70 65 22 3a 22 61  72 67 6f 6e 32 69 22 2c  |type":"argon2i",|
```

I tried to execute luksDump on the LUKS2 partition using the `--debug` flag to discover what might be wrong:

```
$ cryptsetup luksDump image.img --debug
# cryptsetup 2.2.2 processing "cryptsetup luksDump image.img --debug"
# Running command luksDump.
# Locking memory.
# Installing SIGINT/SIGTERM handler.
# Unblocking interruption on signal.
# Allocating context for crypt device image.img.
# Trying to open and read device image.img with direct-io.
# Initialising device-mapper backend library.
# Trying to load any crypt type from device image.img.
# Crypto backend (OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020) initialized in cryptsetup library version 2.2.2.
# Detected kernel Linux 5.4.0-72-generic x86_64.
# Loading LUKS2 header (repair disabled).
# Acquiring read lock for device image.img.
# Opening lock resource file /run/cryptsetup/L_8:0
# Verifying lock handle for image.img.
# Device image.img READ lock taken.
# Trying to read primary LUKS2 header at offset 0x0.
# Opening locked device image.img
# Veryfing locked device handle (bdev)
# LUKS2 header version 2 of size 16384 bytes, checksum sha256.
# Checksum:e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855 (on-disk)
# Checksum:730f75dafd73e047b86acb2dbd74e75dcb93272fa084a9082848f2341aa1abb6 (in-memory)
# LUKS2 header checksum error (offset 0).
# Trying to read secondary LUKS2 header at offset 0x4000.
# Reusing open ro fd on device image.img
# Trying to read secondary LUKS2 header at offset 0x8000.
# Reusing open ro fd on device image.img
# Trying to read secondary LUKS2 header at offset 0x10000.
# Reusing open ro fd on device image.img
# Trying to read secondary LUKS2 header at offset 0x20000.
# Reusing open ro fd on device image.img
# Trying to read secondary LUKS2 header at offset 0x40000.
# Reusing open ro fd on device image.img
# Trying to read secondary LUKS2 header at offset 0x80000.
# Reusing open ro fd on device image.img
# Trying to read secondary LUKS2 header at offset 0x100000.
# Reusing open ro fd on device image.img
# Trying to read secondary LUKS2 header at offset 0x200000.
# Reusing open ro fd on device image.img
# Trying to read secondary LUKS2 header at offset 0x400000.
# Reusing open ro fd on device image.img
# LUKS2 header read failed (-22).
# Device image.img READ lock released.
Device image.img is not a valid LUKS device.
# Releasing crypt device image.img context.
# Releasing device-mapper backend.
# Closing read only fd for image.img.
# Unlocking memory.
```

I thought the checksum's might be the issue, so I followed [@frostschutz](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/523887/56816)'s post and tried to replace the on-disk checksum with the in-memory:

```
echo 730f75dafd73e047b86acb2dbd74e75dcb93272fa084a9082848f2341aa1abb6 |
xxd -r -ps - |
dd of=barfoo.img bs=1 seek=448 conv=notrunc
```

This does take me closer to a solution, well, so it seems:

```
$ cryptsetup luksDump image.img --debug
...
# Opening locked device hidden
# Verifying locked device handle (regular file)
# LUKS2 header version 2 of size 16384 bytes, checksum sha256.
# Checksum:730f75dafd73e047b86acb2dbd74e75dcb93272fa084a9082848f2341aa1abb62c (on-disk)
# Checksum:730f75dafd73e047b86acb2dbd74e75dcb93272fa084a9082848f2341aa1abb62c (in-memory)
# ERROR: Forbidden ascii code 0x53 found beyond json data string at offset 4096
# Trying to read secondary LUKS2 header at offset 0x4000.
...
```

I had a look [over here](https://nest.parrot.sh/packages/debian/cryptsetup/-/blob/master/lib/luks2/luks2_disk_metadata.c#L495) to see what might trigger the error and what kind of value is expected. It seems that an empty byte is expected but it finds an "S" (0x53) in ascii. I'm not sure if this is the right command to find the specific `0x53`, but this returns the S as the first letter of "SKUL"

```
$ hexdump -Cs 4096 -n 4100 hidden
00001000  7b 22 6b 65 79 73 6c 6f  74 73 22 3a 7b 22 30 22  |{"keyslots":{"0"|
00001010  3a 7b 22 74 79 70 65 22  3a 22 6c 75 6b 73 32 22  |:{"type":"luks2"|
00001020  2c 22 6b 65 79 5f 73 69  7a 65 22 3a 36 34 2c 22  |,"key_size":64,"|
00001030  61 66 22 3a 7b 22 74 79  70 65 22 3a 22 6c 75 6b  |af":{"type":"luk|
00001040  73 31 22 2c 22 73 74 72  69 70 65 73 22 3a 34 30  |s1","stripes":40|
00001050  30 30 2c 22 68 61 73 68  22 3a 22 73 68 61 32 35  |00,"hash":"sha25|
00001060  36 22 7d 2c 22 61 72 65  61 22 3a 7b 22 74 79 70  |6"},"area":{"typ|
00001070  65 22 3a 22 72 61 77 22  2c 22 6f 66 66 73 65 74  |e":"raw","offset|
00001080  22 3a 22 33 32 37 36 38  22 2c 22 73 69 7a 65 22  |":"32768","size"|
00001090  3a 22 32 35 38 30 34 38  22 2c 22 65 6e 63 72 79  |:"258048","encry|
...
00001410  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00002000  53 4b 55 4c                                       |SKUL|
```

In that case the given ascii code shouldn't be the issue, but something else is. Perhaps a wrong offset of the data segment? I'm not sure.

Anyone who might has an answer to this issue?

*PS. I replaced the real checksums in this thread with some dummy ones.*

**EDIT:**

Full header as shown below:

```
00000000  4c 55 4b 53 ba be 00 02  00 00 00 00 00 00 40 00  |LUKS..........@.|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 04  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00000040  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  73 68 61 32 35 36 00 00  |........sha256..|
00000050  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000060  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  d2 60 cf 74 cb 3b 37 e5  |.........`.t.;7.|
00000070  70 96 d1 82 bc 9f 15 3f  43 77 68 ec da b0 63 28  |p......?Cwh...c(|
00000080  76 9b 86 af 6c 9d bf b9  9e fe 74 3d 74 37 31 2c  |v...l.....t=t71,|
00000090  4a af 79 9d 7a 2e 4a 51  eb cd 13 35 06 29 33 a9  |J.y.z.JQ...5.)3.|
000000a0  b0 f6 70 8e 7e 34 51 71  39 33 38 38 39 64 37 61  |..p.~4Qq93889d7a|
000000b0  2d 33 65 66 30 2d 34 35  34 34 2d 38 39 62 39 2d  |-3ef0-4544-89b9-|
000000c0  61 62 64 35 63 62 32 33  38 33 64 65 00 00 00 00  |abd5cb2383de....|
000000d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000001c0  19 ea 45 fd ec db 5d f8  3c 47 7d 91 b4 ec 6b 58  |..E...].<G}...kX|
000001d0  85 c0 6d fb 16 18 39 d9  83 e0 a8 3c c3 44 97 2c  |..m...9....<.D.,|
000001e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00001000  7b 22 6b 65 79 73 6c 6f  74 73 22 3a 7b 22 30 22  |{"keyslots":{"0"|
00001010  3a 7b 22 74 79 70 65 22  3a 22 6c 75 6b 73 32 22  |:{"type":"luks2"|
00001020  2c 22 6b 65 79 5f 73 69  7a 65 22 3a 36 34 2c 22  |,"key_size":64,"|
00001030  61 66 22 3a 7b 22 74 79  70 65 22 3a 22 6c 75 6b  |af":{"type":"luk|
00001040  73 31 22 2c 22 73 74 72  69 70 65 73 22 3a 34 30  |s1","stripes":40|
00001050  30 30 2c 22 68 61 73 68  22 3a 22 73 68 61 32 35  |00,"hash":"sha25|
00001060  36 22 7d 2c 22 61 72 65  61 22 3a 7b 22 74 79 70  |6"},"area":{"typ|
00001070  65 22 3a 22 72 61 77 22  2c 22 6f 66 66 73 65 74  |e":"raw","offset|
00001080  22 3a 22 33 32 37 36 38  22 2c 22 73 69 7a 65 22  |":"32768","size"|
00001090  3a 22 32 35 38 30 34 38  22 2c 22 65 6e 63 72 79  |:"258048","encry|
000010a0  70 74 69 6f 6e 22 3a 22  61 65 73 2d 78 74 73 2d  |ption":"aes-xts-|
000010b0  70 6c 61 69 6e 36 34 22  2c 22 6b 65 79 5f 73 69  |plain64","key_si|
000010c0  7a 65 22 3a 36 34 7d 2c  22 6b 64 66 22 3a 7b 22  |ze":64},"kdf":{"|
000010d0  74 79 70 65 22 3a 22 61  72 67 6f 6e 32 69 22 2c  |type":"argon2i",|
000010e0  22 74 69 6d 65 22 3a 34  2c 22 6d 65 6d 6f 72 79  |"time":4,"memory|
000010f0  22 3a 36 36 39 38 38 39  2c 22 63 70 75 73 22 3a  |":669889,"cpus":|
00001100  31 2c 22 73 61 6c 74 22  3a 22 2b 6e 4d 47 65 33  |1,"salt":"+nMGe3|
00001110  2f 4c 47 6c 47 31 36 50  42 6b 72 45 6e 36 32 46  |/LGlG16PBkrEn62F|
00001120  64 79 77 68 73 4e 42 52  55 65 31 67 6c 47 4e 39  |dywhsNBRUe1glGN9|
00001130  57 2f 33 53 59 3d 22 7d  7d 2c 22 31 22 3a 7b 22  |W/3SY="}},"1":{"|
00001140  74 79 70 65 22 3a 22 6c  75 6b 73 32 22 2c 22 6b  |type":"luks2","k|
00001150  65 79 5f 73 69 7a 65 22  3a 36 34 2c 22 61 66 22  |ey_size":64,"af"|
00001160  3a 7b 22 74 79 70 65 22  3a 22 6c 75 6b 73 31 22  |:{"type":"luks1"|
00001170  2c 22 73 74 72 69 70 65  73 22 3a 34 30 30 30 2c  |,"stripes":4000,|
00001180  22 68 61 73 68 22 3a 22  73 68 61 32 35 36 22 7d  |"hash":"sha256"}|
00001190  2c 22 61 72 65 61 22 3a  7b 22 74 79 70 65 22 3a  |,"area":{"type":|
000011a0  22 72 61 77 22 2c 22 6f  66 66 73 65 74 22 3a 22  |"raw","offset":"|
000011b0  32 39 30 38 31 36 22 2c  22 73 69 7a 65 22 3a 22  |290816","size":"|
000011c0  32 35 38 30 34 38 22 2c  22 65 6e 63 72 79 70 74  |258048","encrypt|
000011d0  69 6f 6e 22 3a 22 61 65  73 2d 78 74 73 2d 70 6c  |ion":"aes-xts-pl|
000011e0  61 69 6e 36 34 22 2c 22  6b 65 79 5f 73 69 7a 65  |ain64","key_size|
000011f0  22 3a 36 34 7d 2c 22 6b  64 66 22 3a 7b 22 74 79  |":64},"kdf":{"ty|
00001200  70 65 22 3a 22 61 72 67  6f 6e 32 69 22 2c 22 74  |pe":"argon2i","t|
00001210  69 6d 65 22 3a 34 2c 22  6d 65 6d 6f 72 79 22 3a  |ime":4,"memory":|
00001220  35 33 30 39 32 37 2c 22  63 70 75 73 22 3a 31 2c  |530927,"cpus":1,|
00001230  22 73 61 6c 74 22 3a 22  69 73 33 68 38 54 54 43  |"salt":"is3h8TTC|
00001240  63 79 51 6a 74 52 36 45  75 42 61 4c 64 61 50 56  |cyQjtR6EuBaLdaPV|
00001250  61 76 4e 41 73 4d 77 77  59 4b 6b 57 37 70 64 34  |avNAsMwwYKkW7pd4|
00001260  49 53 51 3d 22 7d 7d 7d  2c 22 74 6f 6b 65 6e 73  |ISQ="}}},"tokens|
00001270  22 3a 7b 7d 2c 22 73 65  67 6d 65 6e 74 73 22 3a  |":{},"segments":|
00001280  7b 22 30 22 3a 7b 22 74  79 70 65 22 3a 22 63 72  |{"0":{"type":"cr|
00001290  79 70 74 22 2c 22 6f 66  66 73 65 74 22 3a 22 31  |ypt","offset":"1|
000012a0  36 37 37 37 32 31 36 22  2c 22 73 69 7a 65 22 3a  |6777216","size":|
000012b0  22 64 79 6e 61 6d 69 63  22 2c 22 69 76 5f 74 77  |"dynamic","iv_tw|
000012c0  65 61 6b 22 3a 22 30 22  2c 22 65 6e 63 72 79 70  |eak":"0","encryp|
000012d0  74 69 6f 6e 22 3a 22 61  65 73 2d 78 74 73 2d 70  |tion":"aes-xts-p|
000012e0  6c 61 69 6e 36 34 22 2c  22 73 65 63 74 6f 72 5f  |lain64","sector_|
000012f0  73 69 7a 65 22 3a 35 31  32 7d 7d 2c 22 64 69 67  |size":512}},"dig|
00001300  65 73 74 73 22 3a 7b 22  30 22 3a 7b 22 74 79 70  |ests":{"0":{"typ|
00001310  65 22 3a 22 70 62 6b 64  66 32 22 2c 22 6b 65 79  |e":"pbkdf2","key|
00001320  73 6c 6f 74 73 22 3a 5b  22 30 22 2c 22 31 22 5d  |slots":["0","1"]|
00001330  2c 22 73 65 67 6d 65 6e  74 73 22 3a 5b 22 30 22  |,"segments":["0"|
00001340  5d 2c 22 68 61 73 68 22  3a 22 73 68 61 32 35 36  |],"hash":"sha256|
00001350  22 2c 22 69 74 65 72 61  74 69 6f 6e 73 22 3a 31  |","iterations":1|
00001360  32 38 31 32 35 2c 22 73  61 6c 74 22 3a 22 41 67  |28125,"salt":"Ag|
00001370  71 67 72 76 4c 6a 51 79  55 47 53 45 2b 69 30 34  |qgrvLjQyUGSE+i04|
00001380  64 62 45 69 73 57 59 30  42 72 71 34 38 6d 50 51  |dbEisWY0Brq48mPQ|
00001390  58 34 6c 4c 6c 31 66 49  77 3d 22 2c 22 64 69 67  |X4lLl1fIw=","dig|
000013a0  65 73 74 22 3a 22 30 6f  56 70 44 48 53 71 61 70  |est":"0oVpDHSqap|
000013b0  4c 79 4b 7a 51 33 4c 2b  6a 41 6a 6c 42 4a 72 5a  |LyKzQ3L+jAjlBJrZ|
000013c0  4b 75 67 34 41 5a 58 34  57 52 30 72 2f 36 79 75  |Kug4AZX4WR0r/6yu|
000013d0  6b 3d 22 7d 7d 2c 22 63  6f 6e 66 69 67 22 3a 7b  |k="}},"config":{|
000013e0  22 6a 73 6f 6e 5f 73 69  7a 65 22 3a 22 31 32 32  |"json_size":"122|
000013f0  38 38 22 2c 22 6b 65 79  73 6c 6f 74 73 5f 73 69  |88","keyslots_si|
00001400  7a 65 22 3a 22 31 36 37  34 34 34 34 38 22 7d 7d  |ze":"16744448"}}|
00001410  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00002000  53 4b 55 4c ba be 00 02  00 00 00 00 00 00 40 00  |SKUL..........@.|
00002010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 04  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00002020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00002040  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  73 68 61 32 35 36 00 00  |........sha256..|
00002050  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00002060  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  bd 38 4d c6 e8 cd e1 ef  |.........8M.....|
00002070  90 f7 b2 53 f6 d4 ca b0  05 d6 ce e1 f2 a5 33 76  |...S..........3v|
00002080  20 03 99 fe aa 10 1d 27  76 b8 e4 d9 5d 4f af 5b  | ......'v...]O.[|
00002090  69 2f d2 1a 7a d2 c4 2d  3c 99 d3 db a7 b7 be 65  |i/..z..-<......e|
000020a0  97 e4 40 6b d5 a5 ed 51  39 33 38 38 39 64 37 61  |..@k...Q93889d7a|
000020b0  2d 33 65 66 30 2d 34 35  34 34 2d 38 39 62 39 2d  |-3ef0-4544-89b9-|
000020c0  61 62 64 35 63 62 32 33  38 33 64 65 00 00 00 00  |abd5cb2383de....|
000020d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00002100  00 00 00 00 00 00 40 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |......@.........|
00002110  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000021c0  70 97 bc 3c d6 2a b3 53  7f a9 35 38 af 2d 38 e9  |p..<.*.S..58.-8.|
000021d0  b2 71 d8 6b ac 67 65 c0  41 7e 71 3b 6e aa 57 78  |.q.k.ge.A~q;n.Wx|
000021e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00003000  7b 22 6b 65 79 73 6c 6f  74 73 22 3a 7b 22 30 22  |{"keyslots":{"0"|
00003010  3a 7b 22 74 79 70 65 22  3a 22 6c 75 6b 73 32 22  |:{"type":"luks2"|
00003020  2c 22 6b 65 79 5f 73 69  7a 65 22 3a 36 34 2c 22  |,"key_size":64,"|
00003030  61 66 22 3a 7b 22 74 79  70 65 22 3a 22 6c 75 6b  |af":{"type":"luk|
00003040  73 31 22 2c 22 73 74 72  69 70 65 73 22 3a 34 30  |s1","stripes":40|
00003050  30 30 2c 22 68 61 73 68  22 3a 22 73 68 61 32 35  |00,"hash":"sha25|
00003060  36 22 7d 2c 22 61 72 65  61 22 3a 7b 22 74 79 70  |6"},"area":{"typ|
00003070  65 22 3a 22 72 61 77 22  2c 22 6f 66 66 73 65 74  |e":"raw","offset|
00003080  22 3a 22 33 32 37 36 38  22 2c 22 73 69 7a 65 22  |":"32768","size"|
00003090  3a 22 32 35 38 30 34 38  22 2c 22 65 6e 63 72 79  |:"258048","encry|
000030a0  70 74 69 6f 6e 22 3a 22  61 65 73 2d 78 74 73 2d  |ption":"aes-xts-|
000030b0  70 6c 61 69 6e 36 34 22  2c 22 6b 65 79 5f 73 69  |plain64","key_si|
000030c0  7a 65 22 3a 36 34 7d 2c  22 6b 64 66 22 3a 7b 22  |ze":64},"kdf":{"|
000030d0  74 79 70 65 22 3a 22 61  72 67 6f 6e 32 69 22 2c  |type":"argon2i",|
000030e0  22 74 69 6d 65 22 3a 34  2c 22 6d 65 6d 6f 72 79  |"time":4,"memory|
000030f0  22 3a 36 36 39 38 38 39  2c 22 63 70 75 73 22 3a  |":669889,"cpus":|
00003100  31 2c 22 73 61 6c 74 22  3a 22 2b 6e 4d 47 65 33  |1,"salt":"+nMGe3|
00003110  2f 4c 47 6c 47 31 36 50  42 6b 72 45 6e 36 32 46  |/LGlG16PBkrEn62F|
00003120  64 79 77 68 73 4e 42 52  55 65 31 67 6c 47 4e 39  |dywhsNBRUe1glGN9|
00003130  57 2f 33 53 59 3d 22 7d  7d 2c 22 31 22 3a 7b 22  |W/3SY="}},"1":{"|
00003140  74 79 70 65 22 3a 22 6c  75 6b 73 32 22 2c 22 6b  |type":"luks2","k|
00003150  65 79 5f 73 69 7a 65 22  3a 36 34 2c 22 61 66 22  |ey_size":64,"af"|
00003160  3a 7b 22 74 79 70 65 22  3a 22 6c 75 6b 73 31 22  |:{"type":"luks1"|
00003170  2c 22 73 74 72 69 70 65  73 22 3a 34 30 30 30 2c  |,"stripes":4000,|
00003180  22 68 61 73 68 22 3a 22  73 68 61 32 35 36 22 7d  |"hash":"sha256"}|
00003190  2c 22 61 72 65 61 22 3a  7b 22 74 79 70 65 22 3a  |,"area":{"type":|
000031a0  22 72 61 77 22 2c 22 6f  66 66 73 65 74 22 3a 22  |"raw","offset":"|
000031b0  32 39 30 38 31 36 22 2c  22 73 69 7a 65 22 3a 22  |290816","size":"|
000031c0  32 35 38 30 34 38 22 2c  22 65 6e 63 72 79 70 74  |258048","encrypt|
000031d0  69 6f 6e 22 3a 22 61 65  73 2d 78 74 73 2d 70 6c  |ion":"aes-xts-pl|
000031e0  61 69 6e 36 34 22 2c 22  6b 65 79 5f 73 69 7a 65  |ain64","key_size|
000031f0  22 3a 36 34 7d 2c 22 6b  64 66 22 3a 7b 22 74 79  |":64},"kdf":{"ty|
00003200  70 65 22 3a 22 61 72 67  6f 6e 32 69 22 2c 22 74  |pe":"argon2i","t|
00003210  69 6d 65 22 3a 34 2c 22  6d 65 6d 6f 72 79 22 3a  |ime":4,"memory":|
00003220  35 33 30 39 32 37 2c 22  63 70 75 73 22 3a 31 2c  |530927,"cpus":1,|
00003230  22 73 61 6c 74 22 3a 22  69 73 33 68 38 54 54 43  |"salt":"is3h8TTC|
00003240  63 79 51 6a 74 52 36 45  75 42 61 4c 64 61 50 56  |cyQjtR6EuBaLdaPV|
00003250  61 76 4e 41 73 4d 77 77  59 4b 6b 57 37 70 64 34  |avNAsMwwYKkW7pd4|
00003260  49 53 51 3d 22 7d 7d 7d  2c 22 74 6f 6b 65 6e 73  |ISQ="}}},"tokens|
00003270  22 3a 7b 7d 2c 22 73 65  67 6d 65 6e 74 73 22 3a  |":{},"segments":|
00003280  7b 22 30 22 3a 7b 22 74  79 70 65 22 3a 22 63 72  |{"0":{"type":"cr|
00003290  79 70 74 22 2c 22 6f 66  66 73 65 74 22 3a 22 31  |ypt","offset":"1|
000032a0  36 37 37 37 32 31 36 22  2c 22 73 69 7a 65 22 3a  |6777216","size":|
000032b0  22 64 79 6e 61 6d 69 63  22 2c 22 69 76 5f 74 77  |"dynamic","iv_tw|
000032c0  65 61 6b 22 3a 22 30 22  2c 22 65 6e 63 72 79 70  |eak":"0","encryp|
000032d0  74 69 6f 6e 22 3a 22 61  65 73 2d 78 74 73 2d 70  |tion":"aes-xts-p|
000032e0  6c 61 69 6e 36 34 22 2c  22 73 65 63 74 6f 72 5f  |lain64","sector_|
000032f0  73 69 7a 65 22 3a 35 31  32 7d 7d 2c 22 64 69 67  |size":512}},"dig|
00003300  65 73 74 73 22 3a 7b 22  30 22 3a 7b 22 74 79 70  |ests":{"0":{"typ|
00003310  65 22 3a 22 70 62 6b 64  66 32 22 2c 22 6b 65 79  |e":"pbkdf2","key|
00003320  73 6c 6f 74 73 22 3a 5b  22 30 22 2c 22 31 22 5d  |slots":["0","1"]|
00003330  2c 22 73 65 67 6d 65 6e  74 73 22 3a 5b 22 30 22  |,"segments":["0"|
00003340  5d 2c 22 68 61 73 68 22  3a 22 73 68 61 32 35 36  |],"hash":"sha256|
00003350  22 2c 22 69 74 65 72 61  74 69 6f 6e 73 22 3a 31  |","iterations":1|
00003360  32 38 31 32 35 2c 22 73  61 6c 74 22 3a 22 41 67  |28125,"salt":"Ag|
00003370  71 67 72 76 4c 6a 51 79  55 47 53 45 2b 69 30 34  |qgrvLjQyUGSE+i04|
00003380  64 62 45 69 73 57 59 30  42 72 71 34 38 6d 50 51  |dbEisWY0Brq48mPQ|
00003390  58 34 6c 4c 6c 31 66 49  77 3d 22 2c 22 64 69 67  |X4lLl1fIw=","dig|
000033a0  65 73 74 22 3a 22 30 6f  56 70 44 48 53 71 61 70  |est":"0oVpDHSqap|
000033b0  4c 79 4b 7a 51 33 4c 2b  6a 41 6a 6c 42 4a 72 5a  |LyKzQ3L+jAjlBJrZ|
000033c0  4b 75 67 34 41 5a 58 34  57 52 30 72 2f 36 79 75  |Kug4AZX4WR0r/6yu|
000033d0  6b 3d 22 7d 7d 2c 22 63  6f 6e 66 69 67 22 3a 7b  |k="}},"config":{|
000033e0  22 6a 73 6f 6e 5f 73 69  7a 65 22 3a 22 31 32 32  |"json_size":"122|
000033f0  38 38 22 2c 22 6b 65 79  73 6c 6f 74 73 5f 73 69  |88","keyslots_si|
00003400  7a 65 22 3a 22 31 36 37  34 34 34 34 38 22 7d 7d  |ze":"16744448"}}|
00003410  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00004000  31 77 5b 25 65 81 f3 e7  d8 4b d2 e1 53 db d8 79  |1w[%e....K..S..y|
```

Comment: Your hexdump output is incomplete so - is the json actually just cut off like that? Can you post the whole thing? The json parser may be fine encountering NULL bytes (which it shouldn't, but... it's an implementation detail) then complain about the first byte that can't be valid json anymore. Still means your header is damaged somehow, not sure if recoverable or not...

Comment: @frostschutz Sure!! I've just placed the full hexdump of the whole header in the topic above (below the EDIT:). Let me know if you need anything else. I've read the LUSK2 specs as well and I guess I learned a lot already, but I wasn't able to recover this, yet. Hopefully it will be.

Comment: OK the problem seems to be, the secondary luks header should be at 0x4000, but for you, it's at 0x2000. It's the same problem further down, the offset in the secondary header is also wrong. How exactly did you extract the image, is it possible offsets were changed in the process? Otherwise, is this disk maybe a part of a RAID 0 or similar striping with everyother stripe missing? Once you fix the offsets the checksums actually come out correct and luksDump works but of course, that does not mean you will be able to open it at all, if this problem continues further down the road...

Comment: hmmmm... I actually used dd for this: `dd skip=1187741696 if=myimage.vma of=image.img bs=1`. I tried fdisk to just restore the partition, starting at that specific sector and mount it at a loop device, but cryptsetup returned even less information with that method. Mounting to a mount point isn't possible because of the `unknown filesystem type 'crypto_LUKS'.` error. It seems the image is created in proxmox, but the LUKS2 disk isn't extractable, so that's why I just manually extracted that one from the image and tried to restore it.

Comment: you might have to use `vma extract` or similar tool that can handle vma for that or do this within the VM (like a rescue system or whatever). just guessing, I'm not too familiar with this format

Comment: Thanks for your help so far! Guess I have to try recovering the .vma file to actually extract the LUKS image. Somehow it is only able to extract one image thus far. I'll update this post when I made any progress. Thanks again :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136741/discussion-between-erik-van-de-ven-and-frostschutz).